# Estimates for round numbers with error term $O(\frac{x}{\ln x})$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Call a positive integer $n$ round if it has no prime factors greater than $\sqrt{n}$

Let $R(x)$ denote the number of round integers $\leq x$

Estimate $R(x)$ to within an error $O(\frac{x}{\log x})$ ?

Hint: Estimate first the slightly different counting function $$ R_0(x) = \# \{n \leq x : p|n \Rightarrow p\leq \sqrt{x} \}$$

and then show that the difference between $R(x)$ and $R_0(x)$ is of order
$O(\frac{x}{\log x})$ and thus negligible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also just show $R(x) = \ln(2)x+O(\frac{x}{\log x})$ directly. First note $x-R(x) = $

$$\#\{n \le x : \exists p > \sqrt{n}, p \mid n\} = \sum_{n \le x} \sum_{p > \sqrt{n} \\ p \mid n}1 = \sum_{p \le x} \sum_{n \le x \\ n \le p^2 \\ p \mid n} 1 = \sum_{p \le \sqrt{x}} \sum_{n \le p^2 \\ p \mid n} 1 + \sum_{\sqrt{x} \le p \le x} \sum_{n \le x \\ p \mid n} 1.$$ The first sum is handled as $$\sum_{p \le \sqrt{x}}\sum_{n \le p^2 \\ p \mid n} 1 = \sum_{p \le \sqrt{x}} p = O(\frac{x}{\log x}).$$ The second sum is $$\sum_{\sqrt{x} \le p \le x}\sum_{n \le x \\ p \mid n} 1 = \sum_{\sqrt{x} \le p \le x} \lfloor \frac{x}{p} \rfloor,$$ which we showed in the previous answer is $(1-\ln 2)x+O(\frac{x}{\log x})$.

Comment: the same goes here , $\ln \ln x - \ln \ln \sqrt{x} = \ln 2$ and does not vanish as $x$ goes to $\infty$

Comment: @Ahmad thanks! fixed this one as well.

Comment: $R(x)$ should be $(1-\ln 2)x +O(\frac{x}{\ln x})$ all the rest is correct.

Comment: @Ahmad No it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proof that $R_0(x) = \ln(2)x+O(\frac{x}{\log x})$. I'll leave it to you to do the other part of the question, namely that $R(x) = R_0(x)+O(\frac{x}{\log x})$.

First note that, for any $n \le x$, there can be at most one prime $p$ greater than $\sqrt{x}$ with $p \mid n$. Therefore,

$$x-R_0(x) = \#\{n \le x : \exists p > \sqrt{x}, p \mid n\} = \sum_{\sqrt{x} \le p \le x} \sum_{n \le x \\ p \mid n} 1 = \sum_{\sqrt{x} \le p \le x} \lfloor \frac{x}{p} \rfloor$$ $$= \sum_{\sqrt{x} \le p \le x} \left[\frac{x}{p}+O(1)\right] =x\left[\log\log(x)-\log\log(\sqrt{x})+O(\frac{1}{x})\right]+O(\frac{x}{\log x})$$  $$= (1-\ln 2)x+O(\frac{x}{\log x}),$$ where we used $$\sum_{p \le y} \frac{1}{p} = \log\log y + c + O(\frac{1}{y})$$ for some absolute constant $c$. So, $R_0(x) = \ln(2)x+O(\frac{x}{\log x})$, as desired.

Comment: there is something wrong here, $\ln \ln x-\ln \ln \sqrt{x} = \ln 2$ and so $R_0(x) = (1-\ln 2)x +O(\frac{x}{\ln x})$ or am i missing something here ?!

Comment: @Ahmad What the heck..... you seem to be right. So since everything else in my answer is correct, $R_0(x)$ has to be $(1-\ln 2)x+O(\frac{x}{\ln x})$. How is my intuition so off here.... Welp, that's for me to figure out. Thanks a lot for catching that error.

Comment: @Ahmad ok, I fixed the answer.